# How do I express $f(z)= \frac{6z}{z^2 - 4z + 13}$ as a power series centered at 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am having trouble solving this power series problem because I usually go about decomposing the $f(z)$ and then using geometric series, but the method doesn't seem to work with this because I get $\frac{A}{z- 2 - 3i} + \frac{B}{z-2+3i}$, which gives me an system that turns out to be contradictory.

Comment: It is easiest to expand about $z=2$ (complete the square). But if you want to expand about $0$, the partial fractions procedure will work.

Comment: I have been trying to expand around 0, but get the equality $Az - A(2-3i) + Bz - B(2 + 3i) = 6z$ and from this I get the system $A + B = 6$,  $-2A - 2B = 0$  and $3A -3B = 0$, which gives me a contraction of 12=0 in when substituting into the second equation. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Don Your problem is that you assume $A, B \in \Bbb{R}$. Don't make two equations out of the $-A(2-3i)-B(2+3i)=0$ part. Simply solve the two-equation two-variable linear system with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid complex numbers altogether and are happy to be able to compute as many coefficients in the power series expansion as you want without having a closed formula, note that you can rewrite
$$
\frac{6z}{z^2-4z+13}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
$$
as
$$
6z=(z^2-4z+13)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.
$$
From the latter you get immediately $a_0=0$, $a_1=\frac6{13}$ and the recursive relation
$$
13a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}+a_n=0
$$
which allows you to compute $a_{n+2}$ for all $n\geq0$.

Comment: This is pretty cool! I bet if you solved the recurrence relation using diagonalization to compute a formula for the power of a matrix, the complex numbers would be zeroes of the characteristic polynomial, which shows how this recurrence relation and the complex partial fraction decomposition that is going on are related.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: of course the two problems are equivalent once you want to solve the recurrence relation exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By a partial fraction decomposition, one gets
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{6z}{z^2 - 4z + 13}&=\frac{3+2i}{-2+3i+z}+\frac{3-2i}{-2-3i+z}
\\\\&=-i\frac1{1-\frac{(2+3i)}{13}z}+i\frac1{1+\frac{(2-3i)}{13}z}
\end{align}
$$ then one may use
$$
\frac1{1-az}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n z^n,\quad |az|<1,
$$ to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Here is the system that you should get using partial fraction decomposition:
$$A+B=6$$
$$A(-2+3i)+B(-2-3i)=0$$

This is not a contradictory system if you allow $A$ and $B$ to be complex. There is a solution. If you get stuck, [here is a link to the solution of this system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%3D6;+a(-2%2B3i)%2Bb(-2-3i)%3D0).

Comment: Do you know how to get the solution $3 - 2i$ and $3 + 2i$? I have checked a few times and from this I keep getting $A$ and $B$ to be $4 + 3i$ and $-2+ 3i$ respectively. This seems to make sense since $A = 6-B$, so I don't know how wolfram alpha solved it.

Comment: We have $A=6-B$ from the first equation, so substitute into the second: $$(6-B)(-2+3i)+B(-2-3i)=0$$ Distribute the $-2-3i$ coefficient over the $6-B$: $$-12+18i+(2-3i)B+B(-2-3i)=0$$ Add like terms: $$-12+18i+(-6i)B=0$$ Add both sides by $12-18i$: $$(-6i)B=12-18i$$ Multiply both sides by $i$: $$6B=12i+18$$ Divide both sides by $6$: $$B=2i+3$$ We also have the following: $$A=6-B=6-(2i+3)=6-2i-3=3-2i$$

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very clear. I was a little confused with the $i$'s.